# Добавление из формы html в модель

Tags: django, django-admin

Мне нужно из формы HTML из нескольких полей добавить данные в модель. Позже вытащить их. Разобралась с этим. Вопрос: если одно из полей `foreign key`, как тогда? Скиньте ссылки, примеры или напишите как сделать с fk

Типо примера

```
class One(models.Model):
    name1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

```
class Two(models.Model):
    name2 = models.ForeignKey(One)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Если поле FK, то чтобы его сохранить в модель нужно передавать в POST его id. Django формы умеют его преобразовывать в объет и сохранять как нужно. В ручную же вам стоит попробовать пеердавать в качетве значения модели id. Если не получится, то предварительно стоит найти объект по id, а затем передавать объект как парметр для поля модели

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, как получить и записать данные, отправленные через пост запрос:

```
def index(request):
    name2 = request.POST.get('name2')
    text = request.POST.get('text')

    instance_one = One.objects.get(pk=name2)  # если  name2 это id объекта модели One
    # или instance_one = One.objects.get(name1=name2) ecли объект модели One нужно получать по полю name1 (оно должно быть уникально)

    new_instance = Two()  # теперь можно создать новый объект модели Two, и записать туда все значения
    new_instance.name2 = instance_one
    new_instance.text = text
    new_instance.save()
```

Вот [тут](https://metanit.com/python/django/5.3.php) хорошо описан процесс работы с моделями

[Это](https://metanit.com/python/django/4.1.php) поможет проще обрабатывать и сохранять данные

Comment: Думаю, лучше ссылаться на офиициальную документацию. А так ответ верный